# Bin data into quantiles using cut - getting missing values

Tags: r

I have a dataframe:

```
a <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4), 2,2)
colnames(a) <- c("a", "b")
df <- as.data.frame(a)

> df
  a b
1 1 3
2 2 4
```

First, I calculate quartilies of "a" column:

```
> quantile (df$a)
  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
1.00 1.25 1.50 1.75 2.00
```

Then, I would like to categorize column "b" using quartiles from column "a":

```
> cat.b<-cut(df$b, quantile (df$a,))
> cat.b  
[1] <NA> <NA>  
Levels: (1,1.25] (1.25,1.5] (1.5,1.75] (1.75,2]
```

As you can see, R gives NA for both "b" values as they are above the highest quartile of "a".

However, I would like the resulting "cat.b" vector to look like:

```
> cat.b
[1]
">2"    ">2"
```

Could you please tell me how to do it in R.

Thank you

Comment: What part of 3 and 4 are not in the range 1-2 are you having difficulty with?

Comment: Both of them are not in this range, DWin

Comment: It is great! Thank you so much, Roman Luštrik!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two values are not in range. You can circumvent this by making another break. I chose `Inf`, you can use a finite value.

```
cat.b <- cut(df$b, c(-Inf, quantile(df$a), Inf))
#next line can be done better, but illustrates the purpose
levels(cat.b)[length(levels(cat.b))] <- ">2" 
levels(cat.b)[1] <- "<1"

cat.b
[1] >2 >2
Levels: (1,1.25] (1.25,1.5] (1.5,1.75] (1.75,2] >2
```

Comment: +1, I would add `-Inf` also, just for the sake of completeness. `c(-Inf,quantile(df$a,),Inf)`